# Text underline if active dropdown link

Tags: html, css

If you're hover a `li`, a dropdown menu appears. If you take the pointer down to the `ul` that appears when you hover, I want the link still have a underline until you take the arrow away from the `ul` or link. This way you know which menu you hovered when the menu drops down.

Any idea how to do this?

```
#scroll-nav .links li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  display: inline;
}
#scroll-nav .links li ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.6s;
    transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    position:absolute; 
    top: 35px;
    left: -25px;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
    z-index:-1111111111111111;
    letter-spacing: 1px !important;
}
#scroll-nav .links li ul a {
    letter-spacing: 1px !important;
}
#scroll-nav .links li:hover ul {
    max-height: 1000px;
}
#scroll-nav .links a {
    margin-right: 40px;
    color: #383838;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#scroll-nav .links li:hover ul {
max-height: 1000px;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to affect a parent element, or element placed before the current one, based on an elements hover state through CSS. You might consider an alternate HTML structure to allow an [adjacent sibling selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) based on the `ul`'s hover state.

Without being able to see your current HTML structure it will be difficult to help any further. Would you mind posting your example to http://jsfiddle.net or a similar site?

Comment: You can see the Shopify store live here: www.eldecosmetics.com. Password is pruget

Comment: Ok, on the site, theres a selector: `#scroll-nav .links li ul a:hover, #scroll-nav .links li a:hover`. You can simply change the `:hover` to be on the `.links li` and then select the _direct child_ `<a>`:

`#scroll-nav .links li ul a:hover, #scroll-nav .links li:hover > a`